# Cumulative sum in jq

Tags: jq

I have a series of `[timestamp, count]` pairs in an array and a want to compute the cumulative sum at each timestamp using `jq`. How could I do that?

Here a sample data set:

```
[
  [1431047957699, 1],
  [1431047958269, 1],
  [1431047958901, 1],
  [1431047959147, -1],
  [1431047960164, 1]
]
```

And the expected result:

```
[1431047957699, 1],
[1431047958269, 2],
[1431047958901, 3],
[1431047959147, 2],
[1431047960164, 3]
```

Is it possible to do this with `jq`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is quite general (e.g. it can be used with an array of objects):

```
def accumulate(f):
  reduce .[1:][] as $row
    ([.[0]];
     . as $x
     | $x + [ $row | (f = ($x | .[length-1] | f) + ($row|f)  ) ] );

accumulate(.[1])
```

If you are using a sufficiently recent version of jq, then "$x |
 .[length-1]" can be simplified to "$x[-1]".

#### Solution using foreach

If your jq has foreach, then the following variant can be used.  It would be particularly appropriate if a stream of values rather than array is wanted.

```
def accumulates(f):
  foreach .[] as $row
    (0;
     . + ($row | f) ;
     . as $x | $row | (f = $x));
```

Usage:

For a stream: `accumulates(.[0])`

For an array: `[accumulates(.[0])`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, will try it out later this week and will choose which one I accept then.

Answer (score 2):

Take a functional approach to this and create an update function that will create the updated values with the cumulative sum.

```
def accumulate(acc):
    select(length > 0) |
    (.[0][1] + acc) as $next |
    (.[0] | .[1] = $next), (.[1:] | accumulate($next))
    ;
[accumulate(0)]
```

Here, we break the array into "head" and "tail" updating the head with the current sum and recursively update the tail.  The results are placed back into a new array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, will try it out later this week and will choose which one I accept then.

Comment: `accumulate/1` as defined here will not benefit from jq's tail-recursion optimization and will thus blow up on large array inputs. It would be  possible to resolve this issue by using a 0-arity helper function.